# Separate paragraphs within (theorem) environments from outer text

Tags: spacing

I have some theorem environments consisting of paragraphs. I use `\parindent0em` and `\parskip0.5em`. After the environment, there is a space to the first outer paragraph, but it's nearly the same as between the paragraphs within the theorem environment. How can I solve this problem? I want to make clear that it's the end of the environment.

Or another situation: I have a text divided into some paragraphs. Then, let's say, the first three ones form a block as somehow belonging (stronger) together, the next two paragraphs form another block belonging together. How can I display that as a difference?

Should I use `\bigskip` or `\bigbreak` in such situations?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\parindent0em
\parskip0.5em

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{bla}{bla}

\begin{document}

\begin{bla}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{bla}
%\bigbreak  ?
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: it's not possible to say how to set off the theorem environments without knowing what document class and theorem package you are using.  it would be much easier to help if you provided a small compilable example that illustrates what you're seeing now.

Comment: Done. I think, a solution would be to decrease `\parskip0.5em` a little bit so that the difference becomes clearer.

What about the general situation when some consecutive paragraphs belong together and one wants to consider them as groups?

Comment: ah!  you didn't say you were using `\theoremstyle{remark}`.  that doesn't add *and* extra space above or below a theorem.  try using `\theoremstyle{definition}'.  the heading is bold (but can be changed) and the text is normal upright.  and the spacing above and below is the same as that for `\theoremstyle{plain}` (and can also be changed).  of course, you make everything harder by setting the paragraph indent to zero.

Comment: as i see it, the most reliable way to "keep paragraphs together in a block" is to manually add space between the blocks.  all bets are off when a page break occurs at a paragraph break (in either case).

Comment: "to manually add space between the blocks"
What's the best way to add space?

Comment: to manually add space, `\bigskip` is probably the easiest/most obvious.  `\vspace{...}` would also work, and, unless `\vspace*` were used, would disappear at page (or column) breaks.  since you have increased the `\parskip` rather a lot, `\medskip` is probably too small to be noticed easily.  you might consider resetting `\medskip` and `\bigskip` to overcome that discrepancy.